# How to fix RocksDBException Error in KafkaStream

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to implement my first Kafka Streams Java App for WordsCount.
Kafka-clients.
The error thrown up

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rocksdb/RocksDBException

I have seen a few resource regarding the same error which states there is some bug in Kafka. Is it true?

The jar file used:: Kafka-streams-0.11.0.0.jar,
Kafka-clients-0.11.0.0.jar.

After defining Streams. Config. This is the code I have written.

```
KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();
    // 1- create a stream from kafka
    KStream<String,String> wordCountInput = 
builder.stream("input_topic");

    KTable<String,Long> wordCountsz = wordCountInput.mapValues(textline-> textline.toLowerCase())
                                                    .flatMapValues(loweredcaseTextLine-> Arrays.asList(loweredcaseTextLine.split(" ")))
                                                    .selectKey((ignoredKey,word)->word)
                                                    .groupByKey()
                                                    .count("stotre");
    wordCountsz.to(Serdes.String(),Serdes.Long(),"output_topic");
    KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(builder,config);
    streams.start();
    System.out.println(streams.toString());

    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(streams::close));
```

Error:

```
 Exception in thread "word-count-app-698a6ff3-ded7-43c4-ada0-d51263f04f33-StreamThread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/rocksdb/RocksDBException
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.get(RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.java:56)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.get(RocksDBKeyValueStoreSupplier.java:35)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopologyBuilder.build(TopologyBuilder.java:1236)
        at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.TopologyBuilder.build(TopologyBuilder.java:1179)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.createStreamTask(StreamThread.java:1234)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask(StreamThread.java:294)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.retryWithBackoff(StreamThread.java:254)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.addStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:1313)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$1100(StreamThread.java:73)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned(StreamThread.java:183)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:363)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:310)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1078)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1043)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests(StreamThread.java:582)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:553)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.rocksdb.RocksDBException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: `ClassDefNotFound` usually indicate an issue with the class path or version of a dependency. Is the RocksDB dependency in the classpath and available?

Comment: Thanks! my foolishness! The path for rocksdb jar was not correct

Answer (score 1):

This is a foolish question since the solution is too naive to mention!
But since there may be some who just like me, follow some online resources and code it up and end up frustrated when the execution breaks.

I had to just add rocksdb jar! I changed my jars to 1.0.2

Actually, the resource I studied did not have any mention of this rocksdb!
Although I understood the issue but since there was a demo of how the code on the internet was working fine without any mention of rocksdb!!
It forced me to think that maybe something else happened!

Sorry for this unnecessary story! Hope it helps all!
Don't follow resources blindly like me !